# Proving that when the normal unit vector $N$ is parallel to the position vector $\gamma(t)$ then the image $\gamma(I)$ is part of circle

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, curves

In other words, consider $\gamma: I \subset \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ a normal curve with positive curvature. We then assume that the normal unit vector $N$ of the curve is everywhere parallel with the position vector  $\gamma(t)$, in other words
\begin{align}
N(t) = c \gamma(t).
\end{align}

Now we do not know if the curve is of arc length or not, so we are obliged to use the generalized Serret-Frenet formulas. It's known that the first three give
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
T(t) &= \dfrac{\gamma'(t)}{||\gamma'(t)||}\\
N(t) &= T(t) \times B(t)  = \dfrac{\gamma'(t) \times\left\{ \gamma'(t)\times\gamma''(t) \right\}}{||\gamma'(t)||\cdot||\gamma'(t) \times \gamma''(t)||}\\
B(t) &= \dfrac{\gamma'(t) \times \gamma''(t)}{||\gamma'(t) \times \gamma''(t)||}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which, tested by my calculations does not lead to anything that is of interest. If we take the first derivatives, it's again known that
\begin{align}
N'(t) = -u(t) k(t)T(t) + u(t) \tau(t)B(t)
\end{align}
where $u$ is a function of the Euclideian norm of the length, again useless since we do not know the form of the curve.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: In any "abstract" exercise/proof, you may *always* assume the curve is parametrized by arclength. Only when confronted with a specific (non-arclength-) parametrized curve must you use the general formulas to compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector $N(t)$ is perpendicular to $\gamma'(t)$, hence:
$$
\gamma'(t)\cdot\gamma(t)=0\ \implies
{d\over dt}\big(\gamma(t)\cdot\gamma(t)\big)=0
\ \implies \|\gamma(t)\|=\text{constant}.
$$

Comment: To clarify notation, you mean the inner product right?

Comment: @algevristis Yes, of course: scalar product.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my book the standard notation for scalar product is $<,>$ so I got a little confused.

Comment: How did you come up with the first equation? I mean sure we can write 
\begin{align}
\langle N(t),\gamma'(t)\rangle=0
\end{align}

Comment: Yes my mistake. How? The exercises states that $\gamma(t)$ is the position vector, ie. the simple $\gamma(t)$ parameterization. Why did you derivate it?

Comment: @algevristis See your second equation, the one defining $N(t)$. But it is obvious that the normal is orthogonal to the tangent.

Comment: @algevristis $a \times b$ is a vector that is orthogonal to both $a$ and $b$ by definition.

Comment: Oh didn't see it. Sorry sirs. Thank you @Intelligentipauca.